# Calculating total in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to calculate the total price in the following way. However, when I log the total value at the bottom, I always get 0 logged.

I wish to store total in a variable so I can use it later on to compare values.

```
  let total = 0;

  cy.get('[cy-data="order-summary-products-product"]').each(
    ($product, index, $list) => {
      const productQuantity = $product.attr("cy-data-product-quantity");
      const productPrice = $product.attr("cy-data-product-price");

      total += productPrice * productQuantity;

      cy.wrap($product)
        .find('[cy-data="order-summary-products-modifier"]')
        .each(($modifier, index2, $list2) => {
          const modifierQuantity = $modifier.attr("cy-data-modifier-quantity");
          const modifierPrice = $modifier.attr("cy-data-modifier-price");

          total += modifierPrice * modifierQuantity;
        });
    }
  );

cy.log(total) //Always get 0 logged
```

Comment: How about replacing the `.each` with a `.then`, looping over the data like you did (using a `for` loop) and loggind the data after the loop, still inside the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress has a env() method that you can use globally to store whatever you need.

```
Cypress.env('totalQuantity') = 0;    

cy.get('[cy-data="order-summary-products-product"]').each(
($product, index, $list) => {
  const productQuantity = $product.attr("cy-data-product-quantity");
  const productPrice = $product.attr("cy-data-product-price");

  Cypress.env('totalQuantity') += productPrice * productQuantity;

  cy.wrap($product)
    .find('[cy-data="order-summary-products-modifier"]')
    .each(($modifier, index2, $list2) => {
      const modifierQuantity = $modifier.attr("cy-data-modifier-quantity");
      const modifierPrice = $modifier.attr("cy-data-modifier-price");

      Cypress.env('totalQuantity') += modifierPrice * modifierQuantity;
    });
});
```